# Two processes sharing the same UDP port for sending

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, udp

My application consists of a UDP server receiving high traffic.

I am thinking to increase the capacity throughput of the application and threading is not an option. So multiple instances of the same process is considered.

I was thinking whether it is possible to **reuse the exact same UDP socket** for sending out traffic between two different processes. I am interested only for sending since receiving is handled in another way.

Will setting option on socket to `SO_REUSEADDR` help here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket options SO\_REUSEADDR and SO\_REUSEPORT, how do they differ? Do they mean the same across all major operating systems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t)

Answer (score 4):

You can not create two servers in two different process because second request for binding on same port will be failed so you have to use `SO_REUSEPORT` option which allows socket to bind
follow [Let two UDP-servers listen on the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364434/let-two-udp-servers-listen-on-the-same-port) for your reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t

Comment: Even if SO_REUSEPORT/SO_REUSEADDR to bind the sockets, are there any issues that can arise from this approach. For example what will happen when two processes will try to send a message at the same time, is this something that I should consider?

Comment: I am considering downvoting this answer. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670891/is-there-a-way-for-multiple-processes-to-share-a-listening-socket

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham Your link is about TCP. This question and answer are about UDP.