# How multi processes bind to one udp port

Tags: c, node.js, sockets, udp

I have two applications, one is C-Based, one is NodeJs-Based.
Two apps need process UDP message from same port in one Centos machine.
Is it possible to have 2 programs that bind to same UDP port and take message simultaneously?

In NodeJs, I used dgram:

```
dgram.createSocket({type: "udp4", reuseAddr: true})
```

And in C, I use `SO_REUSEADDR`, `SO_REUSEPORT` parameter for the setting socket.

The problem is: I can not receive any UDP message in application started later. That means only one application can receive UDP message.
Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Go through this link :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364434/let-two-udp-servers-listen-on-the-same-port)

Answer (score 2):

Using `SO_REUSEADDR` or `SO_REUSEPORT` on a UDP socket only work for incoming  multicast or broadcast packets.

If a unicast packet comes in, whether it is delivered to all sockets or just one (and which one) is implementation defined.

Comment: Actually, with `SO_REUSEPORT` it is well defined -- each incoming packet is delivered to exactly one listening socket.  It is designed for load balancing, but that is apparently not the behavior the OP wants.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Can you please provide a reference? I can't find this in man page of socket or [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/)